# Find sum of the roots of quadratic polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

> The zeroes of a quadratic polynomial $x^2+ax+b$ are $c$ and $d$ and the zeroes of a quadratic polynomial $x^2+cx+d$ are $a$ and $b$. Find the value of $a+b+c+d$.

The thing doesn't make sense how to use the two equations to get the sum?
Should I use the Vieta's formulas to find it?

Comment: It is very recommended for you to show what you tried to do. It will help us to give better answers. What do you know based on what is given?

Comment: Please don't put the question in the title only. The title is no replacement for the body.

Comment: I have tried substituting the values of a b c d in product of the roots equation but it didn't work out

Comment: I am sorry but I am just a tenth grader and I came across this question in a math test . I have given the exact details what I have read in the question paper.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** You know that
$$x^2 + ax + b = (x-c)(x-d) = x^2 - (c+d)x + cd\\
x^2 + cx + d = (x-a)(x-b) = x^2 - (a+b)x + ab$$
Now compare the coefficients to get four equations.

Comment: Its not working

Comment: @tapadianewlon What are your equations?

Comment: @tapadianewlon It **is** working. E.g. note that $a+c+d=0=c+a+b$ and conclude that $d=b$. Then note that $cb=cd=b=d=ab$ and draw new conclusions.